# Ant - Java command - IllegalAccessException

Tags: ant

I need to run java class using ant. But when i run a class file, it throws IllegalAccessException.

this is my ant code:

```
<target name="test">

    <java classname="A" classpath=".">
    </java>
</target>
```

I got this exception when i run this target script.

```
[java] java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava can not access a member of class A with modifiers "public static"
     [java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:180)
```

This is my java program

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello java!");
    }
}
```

Where im going wrong?

thanks,
Srinivasan R.

Comment: Does the class need to be `public`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your class A must be public:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello java!");
    }
}
```

Comment: so it would be kind to accept the answer, since it solved your problem